# How to execute python script on webserver?

Tags: python, apache, webserver, hosting, web-crawler

I have a `python` script which downloads images from a website(call it a image crawler), I want to execute this script on `cpanel` at my hosting site in the same way we do for `php` by accessing it with `URL`.I want to execute it on a regular basis, how to do this ?

Edit :

I did this by adding this at the start my `script.py` file:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html>Hello world!</html>"
```

Comment: more lack of motivation for basic research.

Comment: @alandarev: it's good that you want to help beginners, but we are trying to encourage people to do basic research prior to asking questions. No other sites are, to my mind, doing as much to combat [help vampirism](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

Comment: @halfer That is an amazing article you linked, had lots of fun reading. I mostly agree with you, but I still have faith in some people are just being at the very beginning of a learning process and need some direction to go. In my answer, I exactly gave him the direction, rather than answer directly.

Comment: @alandarev: it's certainly a popular article to link to! The "culture of free" is complex on the web, since it has become the norm and so is greatly expected. But help with technology is also rather an outlier, since people don't _generally_ join architecture discussion groups and ask how to build a skyscraper `;-)`. Perhaps the low barriers to entry to technology - ubiquity plus nearly zero cost - have caused this? In any case, whilst it is good to help beginners, I believe _politely_ steering people to asking good questions is a good first step.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you do not have shell access to your webhosting, you shall ask your webhost whether they support Python as a [CGI script](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html).

Comment: Thanks alandarev, I was successfully able to execute the script.